# Is there a way to do this in pandas without using loop?

Tags: python, pandas, data-science

My df at start:

```
A   B   C   D
A1  1   0   True
A2  1   0   False
A3  1   0   True
```

Output(column D is not needed anymore):

```
A   B   C
A1  2   0
A2  1   1
A3  2   0
```

So for each row in df, if there is True in D then increase value of B by 1 else increase the value of C by 1.

Comment: It is considered good form to show your existing code when asking a question here.

Comment: @IanS: Thanks for letting me know this. I will follow this from next time on wards. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

You can create new `df` with [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html) and add to subset of original:

```
df[['B','C']] = df[['B','C']] + pd.concat([df['D'], ~df['D']], 1, keys=['B','C'])
print (df)
    A  B  C      D
0  A1  2  0   True
1  A2  1  1  False
2  A3  2  0   True
```

Or use `loc`:

```
df.loc[df['D'], 'B'] +=  1
df.loc[~df['D'], 'C'] +=  1
print (df)
    A  B  C      D
0  A1  2  0   True
1  A2  1  1  False
2  A3  2  0   True
```

Or use [`mask`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.mask.html) and [`where`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.where.html):

```
df['B'] = df['B'] + df['D']
df['C'] = df['C'] + (~df['D'])

print (df)
    A  B  C      D
0  A1  2  0   True
1  A2  1  1  False
2  A3  2  0   True
```

Last remove column:

```
df = df.drop('D', axis=1)
print (df)
    A  B  C
0  A1  2  0
1  A2  1  1
2  A3  2  0
```

Comment: This is not giving correct output if the input is something like this: dict3 = {'A':['a', 'b', 'c'], 'B': [1, 0, 0], 
'C': [0, 0, 1], 'D': [True, False, False]}

Comment: This is not giving correct output if the input is something like this: dict3 = {'A':['a', 'b', 'c'], 'B': [1, 0, 0], 
'C': [0, 0, 1], 'D': [True, False, False]}. I am getting output like this:            `  A  B  C      D
0  a  2  0   True
1  b  0  1  False
2  c  0  2  False`                                                                                      
but expected output is                                                                                 `  A  B  C      D
0  a  2  0   True
1  b  0  1  False
2  c  0  1  False

Comment: Thank for comment. I am a bit confused, because in question is `if there is True in D then increase value of B by 1 else increase the value of C by 1.` And it is exactly what my answer is. But your output is different, can you explain more? Or something missing?

Comment: I am saying for each row if there is a True in D, then increase the value of B(same row) else increase the value of C(same row).

Comment: I dont understand - first row is True, so B is changed from 1 to 2. In second row, False, C is change from 0 to 1, in last row, is False, so in C 1 is change to 2. It is wrong?

Comment: I think comment before `df = pd.DataFrame({'A':['a', 'b', 'c'], 'B': [1, 0, 0], 'C': [0, 0, 1], 'D': [True, False, False]} )`

Comment: No it is NOT wrong. You are right. I guess, i messed with my input and output. Thank you!